# How can I display a products star rating based on a variable/user input?

Tags: java, html, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am looking for a way to display a star rating using Spring Boot/Java  without using a set value.  I am able to display star ratings if I know the value I want to display, but if it is a changing number based on an average of user ratings, how can I pass in the variable to keep the star rating up to date?  Every tutorial I have found online is either to accept input for a star rating or how to simply display stars.

I currently am using this as a placeholder which displays the 4.3 stars.

`<div class="Stars" style="--rating: 4.3;" aria-label="Rating of this product is 4.3 out of 5."></div>`

I would like to find a way to use the variable name (the averageuser rating) passed in through the controller to display this rating.  How can I achieve this?  Any help is appreciated.

I am editing to add the style.css  It is calculating how to fill in the stars based on the the --rating but this is where I am unsure of how to pass in the variable.  I don't think I even need the aria-label.

```
.Stars {
  --percent: calc(var(--rating) / 5 * 100%);
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: var(--star-size);
  font-family: Times;
  line-height: 1;
}
.Stars::before {
  content: '★★★★★';
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--star-background) var(--percent), var(--star-color) var(--percent));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: What library/framework do you use with Spring? (Flor examples Thymeleaf)

Comment: I am primarily using thymeleaf but have been using some bootstrap as well

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using thyemeleaf,

```
<div class="Stars">
<p style="--rating: 4.3;" th:text="Rating of this product is + ${the_average_user_rating} + out of 5."></p>
</div>
```

Do it in style as well, if you wish instead of 4.3, ${the_average_user_rating} or whatever name you passed from controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone ever has this same question I solved it doing this:

```
<div class="Stars" th:style="|--rating: ${averageRating}|" >
</div>
```

With the averageRating being passed in through the controller.